# Como editar e criar novo registro no DB? Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer a seguinte situação.

Tenho 2 modelos `Custo` e `Custo_Historico` todo o CRUD já está funcionando.

Só que quando eu quero editar um custo ele deve sempre criar um novo registro na Tab de `Custo_Historico`. Alguém tem alguma dica?

Comment: Você pode mostrar quais atributos das duas classes? e qual você vai replicar no histórico?

Comment: Outra coisa se você está usando "_" para separar nomes de classes compostas, o ideal é que não tenha. Ou seja `Custo_Historico` poderia se chamar `CustoHistorico` seguindo algumas guide lines de código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma das formas de fazer esse tipo de operação é utilizando [Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) e sempre que um `custo` for salvo, ele irá gerar um novo registro de `custo_historico`.

Considerando que você implementou um relacionamento 1xN entre `Custo` e `CustoHistórico` (`has_many`/`belongs_to`) e `Custo` tem um atributo chamado valor, podemos utilizar o callback da seguinte forma:

```
class Custo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :custo_historicos
  after_save :gravar_historico

  def gravar_historico
    custo_historicos.create(valor: valor)
  end
end

class CustoHistorico < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :custo
end
```

Ai o histórico de seu custo, fica automático:

```
c = Custo.create(valor: 1.0)
c.custo_historicos
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<CustoHistorico id: 1, valor: #<BigDecimal:68a13e8,'0.1E1',9(27)>, custo_id: 1, created_at: "2016-06-24 11:59:21", updated_at: "2016-06-24 11:59:21">]>


c.update(valor: 2)
c.custo_historicos
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<CustoHistorico id: 1, valor: #<BigDecimal:68a13e8,'0.1E1',9(27)>, custo_id: 1, created_at: "2016-06-24 11:59:21", updated_at: "2016-06-24 11:59:21">, #<CustoHistorico id: 2, valor: #<BigDecimal:68e6790,'0.2E1',9(27)>, custo_id: 1, created_at: "2016-06-24 12:00:14", updated_at: "2016-06-24 12:00:14">]>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @JoãoHenriqueSoares por nada, precisando estamos ai. Obrigado pelo voto.

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma TRIGGER de banco de dados na tabela de custo, que será responsável por armazenar em Custo_Historico o histórico das alterações realizadas.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MON_ALT_CUSTO ON UPDATE custo
FOR REACH ROW
BEGIN
   //... Código para inserir os dados na tabela histórico.
END;
```

Esta seria a forma mais simples. A sintaxe da criação pode
variar dependendo do SGBD que você esteja utilizando.

Comment: Obrigado Roben,
Mas acredito que tenha alguma outra forma de fazer no controller.

Comment: Também é possível, porém terá que ser no método UPDATE de custos. Ao chamar no controller, você executa o INSERT em Historico_Custo. Mas terá que verificar se o UPDATE executou com sucesso, caso contrário o histórico não será válido.